# Utilizar um método de uma classe em outra no Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, método

estou com dificuldades em saber como mostrar um metodo de uma classe em outra, já tentei de varias formas diferentes. O objetivo do código é ler 3 valores sendo o nome o salario e uma taxa de desconto e mostrar, em seguida pedir uma taxa de aumento para acrescentar no valor bruto. No caso estou com dificuldade de mostrar o aumento do salario após receber a porcentagem. Segue o código:

Main:

````
import java.util.Scanner;

import entities.salary;

public class ex2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        salary salario = new salary();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nome: ");
        salario.nome = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Salario Bruto: ");
        salario.salBruto = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Digite a taxa: ");
        salario.taxa = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(salario.toString());
        System.out.println("Qual a porcentagem que deseja aumentar? ");
        Double porcentagem = sc.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println(salario);
        sc.close();
            }

}
 Entidades:  
```package entities;

public class salary {
    public String nome;
    public Double salBruto;
    public Double taxa;
    
    public Double desconto() {
    return salBruto - taxa;
    }
     public void aumentar (Double porcentagem) {
         porcentagem = this.salBruto * (porcentagem/100);
     }
     public String toString() {
         return "Funcionario: " + nome + ", $" + desconto() ;
     }
     

}
````

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que entendi do seu código, você quer calcular o salário - taxa, mostrar pelo método toString(), calcular um aumento com a porcentagem que o usuário dá como entrada e mostrar o novo valor.
Você não consegue mostrar o ganho da porcentagem porque seu método toString() está chamando o método de desconto(). No fim das contas, será realizado o aumento com a porcentagem informada, porém será deduzido novamente pois o método toString() chama o desconto().
Aqui está uma forma como realizei o seu código, verifica se isso te auxilia, caso contrário pode me responder :)

```
public class Salary {
    public String nome;
    public Double salBruto;
    public Double taxa;

    public Double desconto() {
        return salBruto = salBruto - taxa;
    }

    public void aumentar(double porcentagem) {
        this.salBruto = salBruto + (salBruto * porcentagem / 100);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Funcionario " + nome + ", $" + salBruto;
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Salary salario = new Salary();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Nome: ");
        salario.nome = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Salario Bruto: ");
        salario.salBruto = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Digite a taxa: ");
        salario.taxa = sc.nextDouble();
        salario.desconto();
        System.out.println(salario.toString());
        System.out.println("Qual a porcentagem que deseja aumentar? ");
        Double porcentagem = sc.nextDouble();
        salario.aumentar(porcentagem);
        System.out.println(salario);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).